# Low fps on LibGDX

Tags: java, libgdx

Without this code fps is 60-65. But when i use this code, fps down to 50.

Another problem is that the FPS is too low on some devices. However, the game is quite simple. I'm using ShapeRenderer for all shapes. Game is here: [link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.arinso.endurn)

```
    try {
            Thread.sleep((long)(1000/60-Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime()));
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Edit: I solved this problem using this code --> [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23268256/6631751).

Comment: you shouldnt use that code, are you trying to cap fps?

Comment: Why are you converting this to a long ? This division will be seen as a integer division with a full integer result, cast in a floating point type instead.

Comment: And please ... don't write everything into a try&catch block.

Comment: @HannesHauptmann So, what codes should I use for limit fps

Comment: Google up “swap interval opengl“

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can limit the FPS to any value you want in a libgdx application by defining the [foregroundFPS](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/backends/lwjgl/LwjglApplicationConfiguration.html#foregroundFPS) in the config of your app loader.

```
LwjglApplicationConfiguration config = new LwjglApplicationConfiguration();
    config.width = 640;
    config.height = 480;
    config.foregroundFPS = 60; // <- limit when focused
    config.backgroundFPS = 60; // <- limit when minimized
    config.samples =2; // AA for shape renderer.. not textures!
    new LwjglApplication(new libgdxapp(), config);
```

[android config](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/backends/android/AndroidApplicationConfiguration.html)

[Continuous rendering](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Continuous-&-non-continuous-rendering)

Comment: Well, what do I do on the android. And `cfg.samples = 2` didn't work for AA.

Comment: in android you use config.numSamples = 2 instead of samples

Comment: i mean cfg.samples do not work on desktop. And, What is `config.foregroundFPS = 60` code for Android

Comment: The link in my answer foregroundFPS will take you to the config options for the desktop version. I've added the android version to my answer as well. It doesn't have a foregroundFPS option but if you must limit the FPS you can do this manually by disabling continuous rendering which I have also added to my answer.